# How do I generate an array from a string representation of that array?

Tags: php, arrays, code-generation

I want to generate the array $result_array. There is no error at the page, but not works!

## that not works !

```
//BOF: Result Array
 $result_array = '';
 $result_array .= '"messages" => "' . $errors .'",';
 $result_array .= '"this_addr_type" => "' . (int)$_REQUEST['edit'] .'",';
if (ACCOUNT_GENDER == 'true') {
 $result_array .= '"gender_male" => "' . $male .'",';
 $result_array .= '"gender_female" => "' . $female .'",';
}
 $result_array .= '"firstname" => "' . $entry['entry_firstname'] .'",';
 $result_array .= '"lastname" => "' . $entry['entry_lastname'] .'",';
if (ACCOUNT_COMPANY == 'true') {
 $result_array .= '"company" => "' . $entry['entry_company'] .'",';
}
 $result_array .= '"street_address" => "' . $entry['entry_street_address'] .'",';
if (ACCOUNT_SUBURB == 'true') {
 $result_array .= '"suburb" => "' . $entry['entry_suburb'] .'",';
}
 $result_array .= '"postcode" => "' . $entry['entry_postcode'] .'",';
 $result_array .= '"city" => "' . $entry['entry_city'] .'",';
if (ACCOUNT_STATE == 'true') {
 $result_array .= '"state" => "' . $entry['entry_state'] .'",';
}
 $result_array .= '"country" => "' . $entry['entry_country_id'] .'"';
//EOF: Result Array

  $_RESULT = array($result_array);
```

## that works

```
$_RESULT = array(
 "this_addr_type" => (int)$_REQUEST['edit'],
 "gender_male" => $male,
 "gender_female" => $female,
 "firstname" => $entry["entry_firstname"],
 "lastname" => $entry["entry_lastname"],
 "company" => $entry["entry_company"],
 "street_address" => $entry["entry_street_address"],
 "suburb" => $entry["entry_suburb"],
 "postcode" => $entry["entry_postcode"],
 "city" => $entry["entry_city"],
 "state" => $entry["entry_state"],
 "country" => $entry["entry_country_id"]
);
```

Comment: you could run the first string though `eval` .  Not that I'd suggest such a crude, ugly thing but it should work...

Comment: Why are you attempting to do this, there is certainly a better way to accomplish what you need...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're trying to get PHP to treat a string as code. My question would be "why" - but if you MUST do it, you're looking for eval : http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

```
// untested
$_RESULT = eval("return " . "array($result_array)" . ";");
```

Will probably give you the result you're loking for.

The real qusetion is why aren't you just doing this:

```
if (ACCOUNT_GENDER == 'true') {
 $result_array['gender_male'] = $male;
 $result_array['gender_female'] = $female;
}
```

Comment: the array is still not working.
 $result_array .= '"this_addr_type" => ' . (int)$_REQUEST['edit'] .',';
if (ACCOUNT_GENDER == 'true') {
 //$result_array .= '"gender_male" => ' . $male .',';
 //$result_array .= '"gender_female" => ' . $female .',';
}
 $result_array .= '"firstname" => ' . $entry['entry_firstname'] .',';
 $result_array .= '"lastname" => ' . $entry['entry_lastname'] .',';

.................................

$_RESULT = eval("array($result_array)");

Comment: @question_about_the_problem: You should not do it with eval. Use the other way Erik proposes. Besides being the only right way it is muuuuch easier to read.

Comment: because when you are creating your string you aren't quoting the values and you need to. For example, this would be correct:
`$result_array .= "'country' => '{$entry['entry_country_id']}',";` 
Notice the value is quoted.

Comment: @Felix: Thanks for suggestion. I've used second way. That's true "it is muuuuch easier to read"
@Eric: This solutions is better than hurikhan77's solution. I have an another question:
How i can create array as this:
$array("products_image_sm_1" => "", products_image_xl_1" => "" ......... etc);
I want to create that without eval and in the for loop.
for an example:
$parameters_images=array();
for ($f=1; $f<=5; $f++) { $parameters_images = array_merge($parameters_images, array("products_image_sm_$f=>"" )); $parameters_images = array_merge($parameters_images, array("products_image_xl_$f=>"" ));}

Comment: @question_about_the_problem: It would just be: `$parameters_images=array(); for ($f=1; $f<=5; $f++) { $parameters_images["products_image_sm_$f"] = ''; $parameters_images["products_image_xl_$f"] = '';}` I think you should read the basics about arrays: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: @Felix: Thanks, but I know the basicly informations about arrays. I just want to use best way.

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't work that way. A string is not always equivalent to the actual thing you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

The first example just creates an array with one really large string.  The "=>"s are included in that string and are not interpreted to create a new array element.  Look at the second example.  Are the "=>"s there inside of quotes?

Answer (score 0):

You already answered your own question. The first cannot work. You are just creating a long string and then stick that string as single element into an array.

But looking at your two examples I suppose you're wanting to do something like this:

```
$result_array = array();
if($somecondition) {
  $result_array = array_merge($result_array, array("entry1" => "data1", "entry2" => "data2"));
}
if($someothercondition) {
  $result_array = array_merge($result_array, array("other_entry" => "more_data"));
}
$_RESULT = $result_array;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create PHP array like this:

```
$array = array();
```

or

```
$array[] = 'whatever';
```

But in your code, you are using:

```
$result_array .= '"messages" => "' . $errors .'",';
```

Which is not how to create PHP array.

Comment: yes, because I want to gererate the array. I know how i can create manual array.

Answer (score 0):

```
//BOF: Result Array
$_RESULT = array();
$_RESULT["messages"] = $errors;
$_RESULT["this_addr_type"] = (int)$_REQUEST['edit'];
if (ACCOUNT_GENDER == 'true') {
    $_RESULT["gender_male"]    = $male;
    $_RESULT["gender_female"]  = $female;
}
$_RESULT["firstname"]    = $entry['entry_firstname'];
$_RESULT["lastname"]     = $entry['entry_lastname'];
if (ACCOUNT_COMPANY == 'true') {
    $_RESULT["company"]  = $entry['entry_company'];
}
$_RESULT["street_address"]  = $entry['entry_street_address'];
if (ACCOUNT_SUBURB == 'true') {
    $_RESULT["suburb"]      = $entry['entry_suburb'];
}
$_RESULT["postcode"]    = $entry['entry_postcode'];
$_RESULT["city"]        = $entry['entry_city'];
if (ACCOUNT_STATE == 'true') {
    $_RESULT["state"]   = $entry['entry_state'];
}
$_RESULT["country"]  = $entry['entry_country_id'];
//EOF: Result Array
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to do this? Are you storing the array in text somewhere? If it doesn't need to be human readable, you should look at:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

```
// $_RESULT as a string
$str = serialize($_RESULT);

// Back as an array
$arr = unserialize($str);
```